# Accessing HSTORE data in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, hstore

So I set up a postgres server and have it working with hstore values.

As of right now, I have a table books, structured with

```
name:string data:hstore
```

I have created a sample entry to test:

```
Book.create(:name => "My First Book", :data => {'author' => 'Kevin', 'pages' => 368})
```

I have loaded the data into a variable:

```
@book = Book.where("data ? :key", :key => 'pages')
```

(just to test, i realize this query would serve no real purpose...)

I print the data as JSON and this works fine, the entry is found and displayed. However, what I am trying to do is access, say the pages, an hstore value. I did some research and found

```
@book.data['pages']
```

However, when i try to run this, I get

```
undefined method `data' for #<Book::ActiveRecord....
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Active Record `where` will give you an array even if there is only 1 value.

You can do

```
@book = Book.where("data ? :key", :key => 'pages')[0]
```

to get that record

and then

```
@book.data
```

will work as desired.

If you might get multiple records and just using the first found is ok you could also use:

```
@book = Book.where("data ? :key", :key => 'pages').first
@book.data
```

or just

```
@book = Book.where("data ? :key", :key => 'pages').first.data
```

Answer (score 1):

After fiddling around, i found that I simply needed to call:

```
@book[0].data
```